# Куда вставлять api ключ при обращению к api с помощью Retrofit в Android

Tags: android, kotlin, api, retrofit2

Когда я обращался к собственному api (для которого ключ не нужен), я прописывал обращение следующим образом:

```
class ApiClient private constructor() {

    val api: ApiInterface
        get() = retrofit!!.create(
            ApiInterface::class.java)

    init {
        retrofit =
            Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()

    }

    companion object {

        private val BASE_URL = "http://grid.beget.tech/"

        private var apiClient: ApiClient? = null
        private var retrofit: Retrofit? = null

        val instance: ApiClient?
            @Synchronized get() {

                if (apiClient == null) {

                    apiClient =
                        ApiClient()
                }

                return apiClient

            }
    }
}
```

сейчас получаю данные со стороннего api, который предоставляет бесплатные ключи https://apilayer.com/marketplace/exchangerates_data-api#documentation-tab

Но куда мне этот ключ прописать, я не знаю

// там есть примеры кода, но я не уверен, что их можно приспособить к `android`

P.S. С `Retrofit` у меня достаточно небольшой опыт работы

```
@Headers("myapikey")
@GET("loadMedicines.php")
    fun loadMedicinesApi(): Call <ArrayList<MedicationsApiModel>>
```

Comment: Приспособить может и нет, но видно же что ключ пишут в заголовки. В ретрофите они задаются аннотациями `@Headers` над API-методом, или `@Header` на параметре метода. Примеры есть в [документации](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: получается над методом запроса я просто добавляю ещё одну аннотацию, в скобки которой добавляю ключ? (то, как я это понял, добавил в вопрос)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по примеру кода из документации по ссылке, ключ API передаётся в заголовке `apikey`.
В ретрофите заголовки можно задавать несколькими способами.

1. Аннотация к методу (если вас устраивает что ключ будет прописан в открытом виде в коде):

```kotlin
@Headers("apikey: key-value") // key-value - собственно сам ключ
@GET("loadMedicines.php")
    fun loadMedicinesApi(): Call <ArrayList<MedicationsApiModel>>
```

---

2. Аннотация к параметру метода (ключ передаётся параметром метода и вы имеете возможность прятать его любым способом до самого вызова API):

```kotlin
@GET("loadMedicines.php")
    fun loadMedicinesApi(@Header("apikey") String apikey): Call <ArrayList<MedicationsApiModel>>
```

---

3. Если таких методов много, то пихать ключ в каждый не очень удобно, ловчее сделать это в одном месте - при инициализации ретрофита, с помощью `Interceptor`:

```kotlin
class ApiClient private constructor() {

    val api: ApiInterface
        get() = retrofit!!.create(
            ApiInterface::class.java)

    init {
        // создаём клиент с интерсептором, добавляющим заголовок
        var client = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor { chain ->
            val request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("apikey", API_KEY).build()
            chain.proceed(request)
        }.build()

        retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                     .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                     .client(client) // задаём наш модифицированный клиент
                     .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                     .build()

    }

    companion object {

        private val BASE_URL = "http://grid.beget.tech/"
        private val API_KEY = "key-value" // константа, хранящая ключ, при желании можно изменить способ хранения на более безопасный

        private var apiClient: ApiClient? = null
        private var retrofit: Retrofit? = null

        val instance: ApiClient?
            @Synchronized get() {

                if (apiClient == null) {

                    apiClient =
                        ApiClient()
                }

                return apiClient

            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Премного благодарен!